# MySQL Trouble transitioning from Injection to Paramterization

Tags: c++, mysql

I have the following code here that executes a query. Originally, I used SQL Injection to return row results. Hearing I should use parametrization, I rearranged my code and read the MySQL docs on how to do so. I'm using MySQL's C library in a C++ application.

However, it's not returning the results.

I know my SQL statement is 100% fine. It has been tested. The only thing I changed was changing %d (injection) to ?, which accepts the player's ID.

This returns -1. It's a SELECT statement though, so maybe it's normal?

```
    // Get the number of affected rows
    affected_rows = mysql_stmt_affected_rows(m_stmt);
```

This returns 2. This is correct. I have two fields being returned.

```
    // Store the field count
    m_fieldCount = mysql_field_count(&m_conn);
```

This returns 0 (success)

```
    if (mysql_stmt_store_result(m_stmt))
```

Finally, this returns null.

```
    m_result = mysql_store_result(&m_conn);
```

I need m_result so I can read the rows. "mysql_stmt_store_result" sounds similar, but doesn't return MYSQL_RESULT.

```
  m_result = mysql_store_result(&m_conn);

/// <summary>
/// Executes a query.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="query">The query to execute.</param>
/// <returns>Returns true on success, else false.</returns>
bool SQLConnection::executeQuery_New(const char *query)
{
    int param_count = 0;
    int affected_rows = 0;

    // Validate connection.
    if (!m_connected)
        return false; 

    // Initialize the statement
    m_stmt = mysql_stmt_init(&m_conn);
    if (!m_stmt) {
        fprintf(stderr, " mysql_stmt_init(), out of memory\n");
        return false;
    }

    // Prepare the statement
    if (mysql_stmt_prepare(m_stmt, query, strlen(query))) {
        fprintf(stderr, " mysql_stmt_prepare(), INSERT failed\n");
        fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(m_stmt));
        return false;
    }

    // Get the parameter count from the statement
    param_count = mysql_stmt_param_count(m_stmt);
    if (param_count != m_bind.size()) {
        fprintf(stderr, " invalid parameter count returned by MySQL\n");
        return false;
    }

    // Bind buffers 
    // The parameter binds are stored in std::vector<MYSQL_BIND>
    // I need to convert std::vector<MYSQL_BIND> m_bind to MYSQL_BIND *bnd
    MYSQL_BIND *bind = new MYSQL_BIND[m_bind.size()  + 1];

    memset(bind, 0, sizeof(bind) * m_bind.size()); 

    for (int i = 0; i < param_count; i++)
        bind[i] = m_bind[i]; 

    if (mysql_stmt_bind_param(m_stmt, &bind[0]))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, " mysql_stmt_bind_param() failed\n");
        fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(m_stmt));
        return false;
    }

    // Execute the query
    if (mysql_stmt_execute(m_stmt)) {
        fprintf(stderr, " mysql_stmt_execute(), 1 failed\n");
        fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(m_stmt));
        return false;
    }

    // Get the number of affected rows
    affected_rows = mysql_stmt_affected_rows(m_stmt);
    //if (affected_rows == -1) {
    //  fprintf(stderr, " mysql_stmt_execute(), 1 failed\n");
    //  fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(m_stmt));
    //  return false;
    //}

    // Store the field count
    m_fieldCount = mysql_field_count(&m_conn);


    // Store the result
    if (mysql_stmt_store_result(m_stmt)) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, " failed retrieving result\n");
        fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_error(&m_conn));
        int d = mysql_errno(&m_conn);
        return false;
    }

    // This looks similar to the last above statement, but I need m_result. I used mysql_store_result earlier when using injection and it worked fine, but here in this case it returns null. 
    m_result = mysql_store_result(&m_conn);


    // Close the statement
    if (mysql_stmt_close(m_stmt)) {
        /* mysql_stmt_close() invalidates stmt, so call          */
        /* mysql_error(mysql) rather than mysql_stmt_error(stmt) */
        fprintf(stderr, " failed while closing the statement\n");
        fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_error(&m_conn));
        return false; 
    }

    // Delete bind array
    if (bind) {
        delete[] bind;
        bind = NULL;
    }

    return true;
}
```

How I'm adding an int parameter (player's id):

```
void SQLConnection::addParam(int buffer, enum_field_types type, unsigned long length)
{
    MYSQL_BIND bind; 

    memset(&bind, 0, sizeof(bind));

    bind.buffer = (char *)&buffer;
    bind.buffer_type = type;
    bind.is_null = 0;
    bind.length = &length;

    m_bind.push_back(bind);
}
```

My variables and their types:

```
class SQLConnection
{
private: 
    MYSQL m_conn;
    MYSQL_ROW m_row;
    MYSQL_RES *m_result;  
    char m_errorMessage[ERROR_MSG_MAX];
    bool m_connected;
    MYSQL_STMT *m_stmt;
    std::vector<MYSQL_BIND> m_bind;
    int m_fieldCount;
    // ...
```

And finally its calling function at the end of the SQL statement:

```
...WHERE player_id = ?;"); 

conn.addParam(m_id, MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG, 0);

    if (!conn.executeQuery_New(buffer)) {
        conn.close();
        return "";
    }

    // Close the connection.
    conn.close();

    std::string s = conn.getField("max_value_column_name");
```

The error code I get is 2014:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Just for the sake of interest, this is a prior function I used. This worked fine for injection. Using the new function above with parameterization is the one causing the issues.

```
bool SQLConnection::executeQuery(const char *query)
{ 
    // Validate connection.
    if (!m_connected)
        return false;  

    // Execute the query
    int status = mysql_query(&m_conn, query);

    if (status != 0) {
        sprintf(m_errorMessage, "Error: %s", mysql_error(&m_conn)); 
        return false;
    } 

    // Store the result
    m_result = mysql_store_result(&m_conn);

    return true;
}
```

After I started having language religious wars in my head about using C# over C++, I thought I'd give one last attempt here. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
This is how I read in column names prior to parameterization (maybe this code needs to be updated after calling mysql_stmt_store_result(m_stmt)?

```
std::string SQLConnection::getField(const char *fieldName)
{
    MYSQL_FIELD *field = NULL;
    unsigned int name_field = 0;

     mysql_stmt_data_seek(m_stmt, 0);
     mysql_stmt_fetch_column(m_stmt, &bind, 0, 0);
     //mysql_data_seek(m_result, 0);
     //mysql_field_seek(m_result, 0);

     const unsigned int num_fields = mysql_stmt_field_count(m_stmt); 
     // const unsigned int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(m_result);

    std::vector<char *> headers(num_fields);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; (field = mysql_fetch_field(m_result)); i++)
    {
        headers[i] = field->name;

        if (strcmp(fieldName, headers[i]) == 0)
            name_field = i;
    }  

    while ((m_row = mysql_fetch_row(m_result))) {
        return std::string(m_row[name_field]);
    }

    return "";
}
```

Edit:
What I'm finding is in this last function there are equivalent functions for statements, like mysql_num_fields() is mysql_stmt_field_count(). I'm thinking these need to be updated because it's using m_stmt and not m_result anymore, which gives reason to update the functions so m_stmt is used. It's not very apparent how to update the second half of the function though.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a better understanding of how `stmt` works.You can't get the final results by `mysql_store_result()` when you're using `stmt`.

1. You shoud bind several buffers for the statement you're using to accept the result set. You can finish this by [mysql_stmt_bind_result()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-bind-result.html), just like `mysql_stmt_bind_param()`.
2. Then you can use the buffers bound by [mysql_stmt_bind_result()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-bind-result.html) to return row data. You can finish this by [mysql_stmt_fetch()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-fetch.html).
3. Do the fetch method repeatedly, so you can get the whole result set row by row.

The basic sequence of calls:

- mysql_stmt_init
- mysql_stmt_prepare
- mysql_stmt_bind_param
- mysql_stmt_execute
- mysql_stmt_bind_result
- mysql_stmt_store_result
- mysql_stmt_fetch (repeatedly, row by row)
- mysql_stmt_free_result

It works for me.

It's a long time since I finished this part of my project, you'd better read the manual carefully and find more examples of `stmt`.

Sorry for my poor English. Good luck!